# In OpenShift how can we do URL rewriting for external requests

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I tried to find information in the documentation of OpenShift, but could not discover how to use an OpenShift Route to perform URL rewriting. Do routes allow you to perform reverse-proxy like functionality such as URL rewriting?

(Edited 10/16 to add additional information the original author had placed in comments.)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do? Yes, to a certain extent, a route is a reverse proxy. Routes are actually based on HAProxy. But without knowing what you want to do, it's hard to make a more concrete suggestion other than "use a route".

Comment: I want to rewrite-response that is coming from application to my route-url. Original url is my pods-name and as pods are not accessible outside, so wanted to rewrite it to route-urls.

Answer (score 0):

See the [route-specific annotations section of the docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-route-specific-annotations_route-configuration), especially "A route specifying a rewrite target" and Table 3. rewrite-target examples.

Also make sure that you understand how [path based routes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-path-based-routes_route-configuration) work.

In short, the rewrite rule will replace whatever path you specify in your path based routing (`spec.path`) with whatever you specify in your rewrite rule annotation (`haproxy.router.openshift.io/rewrite-target`) .

Comment: I want to do rewrite-response, rewrite-target would help me to route to that particular application.  If there is anything such as rewrite-response, I would change the response going through route.

Comment: I think you are going to have to be more specific. Are you talking about rewriting the response body?